# find piped to xargs with complex command

Tags: bash

I am trying to process DVD files that are in many different locations on a disk.  The thing they have in common is that they (each set of input files) are in a directory named `VIDEO_TS`.  The output in each case will be a single file named for the parent of this directory.

I know I can get a fully qualified path to each directory with:

```
find /Volumes/VolumeName -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" -print0
```

and I can get the parent directory by piping to xargs:

```
find /Volumes/VolumeName -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} dirname {}
```

and I also know that I can get the parent directory name on its own by appending:

```
| xargs -o I{} basename {}
```

What I can't figure out is how do I then pass these parameters to, e.g. HandBrakeCLI:

```
./HandBrakeCLI -i /path/to/filename/VIDEO_TS -o /path/to/convertedfiles/filename.m4v
```

I have read here about expansion capability of the shell and suspect that's going to help here (not using dirname or basename for a start), but the more I read the more confused I am getting!

Comment: `basename` will return the `filename`/`foldername`. `dirname` will return the path to the parent directory.

Comment: Some thing like: `for video_ts in $(find ...); do ./HandBrakeCLI -i ${video_ts} -o /path/to/convertedfiles/filename.m4v; done`

Comment: I get how that would get me all the files to act on as vars (and then to run HandBrakeCLI on them), but there still isn't a mechanism to extract the (target) filename and use it in the for loop - unless I am missing something.

Comment: @ash, that code will fail badly if any directory names have whitespace in them; it also risks trying to expand globs found in filenames.

Comment: @ash, see the first entry in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: BTW, why use `xargs` at all, rather than find `-exec`?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the transformation you want to make on the found filename (and, independently, so did @CharlesDuffy, since we propose the same thing.) Would you be so kind as to provide an actual example of one result of `find` and the invocation of `HandBrakeCLI` you want to perform on it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair point - my hacky (and naive) approach, but you're right.

Comment: @rici Suppose the full path to the VIDEO_TS directory is /Volume/VolumeName/Movies/Gone\ with\ the\ Wind/VIDEO_TS/, the intended output name would be Gone\ with\ the\ Wind.m4v

Comment: I understood that but i lack clarity on the precise invocation of `HandBrakeCLI`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The outputs will all go to a hard-coded directory, with just the filename changing.  Whilst I am writing, could you explain a bit more about notation like dir%/* and dir##*/ please?  I suspect this is the expansion I alluded to?

Comment: @Lorccan, these are parameter expansions. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe; `${dir%/*}` expands to everything before the last `/` in `$dir`; `${dir##*/}` expands to everything *prior to* the last `/`.

Comment: @Lorccan, ...I've added some comments in my code to make that clear.

Comment: Understood! Thanks - and to @rici.  I have plenty to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need `xargs` for this at all: You can read a NUL-delimited stream into a shell loop, and run the commands you want directly from there.

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=/Volumes/VolumeName
dest_dir=/Volumes/OtherName

while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
  name=${dir%/VIDEO_TS} # trim /VIDEO_TS off the end of dir, assign to name
  name=${name##*/}      # remove everything before last remaining / from name
  ./HandBrakeCLI -i "$dir" -o "$dest_dir/$name.m4v"
done < <(find "$source_dir" -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" -print0)
```

See [the article Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) on Greg's wiki, or [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for general information on processing input streams in bash, or [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) to understand the value of using process substitution (the `<(...)` construct here) rather than piping from find into the loop.

---

Also, `find` contains an `-exec` action which can be used as follows:

```
source_dir=/Volumes/VolumeName
dest_dir=/Volumes/OtherName

export dest_dir # export allows use by subprocesses!

find "$source_dir" -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" -exec bash -c '
  for dir; do
    name=${dir%/VIDEO_TS}
    name=${name##*/}
    ./HandBrakeCLI -i "$dir" -o "$dest_dir/$name.m4v"
  done
' _ {} +
```

This passes the found directory names directly on the argument list to the shell invoked with `bash -c`. Since the default object for `for` loop to iterate over is `"$@"`, the argument list, this implicitly iterates over directories found by `find`.

Comment: I've learnt something quite nice here.  What is the `_` doing?

Comment: @ash, the `_` is a placeholder for `$0`. Otherwise you get a VIDEO_TS directory name in there, and it gets skipped in the iteration over `"$@"`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are trying to do, the simplest solution would be to create a little wrapper which takes a path and invokes your CLI:

**File: CLIWrapper**

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "$@"; do
  ./HandBrakeCLI -i "${dir%/*}" -o "/path/to/convertedfiles/${dir##*/}.m4v"
done
```

---

**Edit:** I think I misunderstood the question. It's possible that the above script should read:

```
./HandBrakeCLI -i "$dir" -o "/path/to/convertedfiles/${dir##*/}.m4v"
```

or perhaps something slightly different. But the theory is valid. :)

---

Then you can invoke that script using the `-exec` option to `find`. The script loops over its arguments, making it possible for `find` to send multiple arguments to a single invocation using the `+` terminator:

```
find /Volumes/VolumeName -type d -name "VIDEO_TS" -exec ./CLIWrapper {} +
```